# Allow everything for IdentityServer client?

Tags: c#

I have finished setting up Identity Server, and it is now giving me an invalid scope error. I don't care about scopes, I simply want to allow access to everything, as long as they get the access token initially.

When not passing scope, or passing an empty scope Identity Server complains about no scopes have been allowed, because I don't want any? I have not set any anywhere

How can I get an access token without scopes?

Answer (score 0):

According to OAuth 2.0 specification, an application can request one or more scopes. Which means, you must ask for at least one of the scopes. OIDC specification states that you must ask for at least "openid" scope (required; to indicate that the application intends to use OIDC to verify the user's identity).

So, you cannot get access token without asking for "openid" scope. *"OpenID Connect requests MUST contain the openid scope value"*